# How to set screen resolution for xolvio:webdriver (Meteor)

Tags: meteor, selenium-webdriver, velocity

I'm trying to run my test using `xolvio:webdriver` but it looks like default screen resolution is mobile.

How to set a desktop resolution for the webdriver?

P.S. We're using PhantomJs using `wdio.getGhostDriver`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
browser.
    init(). // be sure to call init first
    setViewportSize({
      width: 1280,
      height: 1024
    }).
```

PhantomJS by default has a low resolution.